# Post install questions

Tags: configuration, linux, log

1. I have installed Tor on a Opensuse 13.2. There is no log files in `/var/log` for Tor, how can i fix this?
2. When I start Tor and press the link "Test for Tor Network Settings" I am told that I an not connected to Tor. How can I address this issue?

Answer (score 2):

- If you've installed tor as a system service through OpenSUSE's package manager:

  1. You can define where tor logs to through use of [`Log`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#Log) directives in the `torrc` file, located by default in `/etc/tor/torrc`.
  2. If it's a system service you'll need to manually configure applications to use Tor, normally through its [`SOCKSPort`](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#SOCKSPort). However if it's a web browser, it's strongly recommended that you use [`Tor Browser`](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en).
- If you've installed a copy of Tor Browser from the above link:

  1. You can retrieve Tor's logs through the green onion menu (`Tor Button`), then selecting `Tor Network Settings`. This should provide you with a button that will copy the logs for Tor to the clipboard, where you can then manually paste them somewhere to review or share them.
  2. A small set of relays do not send outbound traffic from the same address they advertise to receive traffic on. The tor network regularly sends probes out of all exits to find the addresses they connect out from, but this list is not always 100% up to date *(nor could it really ever be)*. As such the https://check.torproject.org/ website may report a "false negative", because it does not recognise the location being connected from as a known exit address.